# Split /24 IPv4 subnet into multiple /28

Tags: ip, gateway, ipv4

I would like to know if it is possible that a subnet /24 that I assigned to a dedicated server (via BGP session) can be divided into smaller subnets without the intervention of those who have access to physical equipment.

What I would like to do is create virtual machines (via Linux) that are from different subnets, not mapped to the /24 gateway.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: To better understand the situation, here's what I want to do.
IPs are fake.
The dedicated server has the IP address 5.183.170.160 and the gateway 5.183.170.1 (on the dedicated server I could add as an alias as many IP addresses as I want from the same subnet /24)
What I want to do is create more bridges to use for different virtual machines, assigning the appropriate IP  from that subnet /28 as the gateway.
How should I proceed so that my /28 gateway is recognized on VMs to access the internet?

Comment: The detailed explanation should be put [into the question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1101836/edit), not in the comment. Instead of picking random IPs, use those [reserved for documentation purposes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737.html), `192.0.2.x`. As for the question itself, you seem to be asking about [proxy ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_ARP). If there is a difficulty in understanding how to configure it, return here, I'll try to explain in the answer.